# Plotting histogram of a slice of a matrix

Tags: matlab, histogram, data-processing

I have a matrix `amp` containing 10 row signals `[1*1001]`. So the total dimension of my data is `[10*1001]`.

Each row is containing amplitude fluctuations(signal). Now by using `plot(f,abs(amp))`, I am plotting all 10 signals on the `f` vector which is having length of `[1*1001]`.
This `f` vector is a frequency axes going from 70 to 110 kHz.

This is the graph which I am plotting.

```
figure,plot(f2,abs(amp));
xlabel('Frequency in KHz');ylabel('amp');
```

[image]

Now I want a histogram at 90Khz, that means at particular 90KHz frequency, how much amplitude of all 10 signals are changing?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data in the code? It is not obvious what you asking.

Comment: You'll need to provide sample data and a picture

Comment: NKN & Dan, thanks for your comments. I have 10 signals(that means 10 rows) which is having lenght of 1*1001. So the total dimension of my data is [10*1001]. now each row is containing amplitude fluctuations(signal). Now by using plot(f,abs(amp)), i am plotting all 10 signals on the f vector which is having lenght of [1*1001]. Moreover, this f vector is a frequncy axes and frequency is starting from 70 to 110 KHz. Now i want a histogram at 90Khz, that means at perticular 90KHz frequency,how much amplitude  of all 10 singnals are changing.

Comment: Without sample and picture, what you explained is not adding much.

Comment: Please edit your original post and add the new information instead of writing them in comments.

Comment: ok.. thanks for your comment @Hoki

Comment: With a frequency vector going from `70` to `110` kHz in `1001` point, the `90 kHz` is at index **501**. So is `histogram( amp(:,501) )` what you are after ?

Comment: ya. this is what i thought as well.

Comment: @Hoki That is also assuming that it is in linear scale, why not just find in the vector f where 90kHz is and index the correct 10*1 from the 10*1001 matrix.

Comment: @GameOfThrows, yes you could use something like `histogram( amp(:,f==90) )` but you'd have to be sure that your vector `f` has a value which is **exactly** 90. The way I understood the question, it seemed to be more about how to get an histogram of the correct slice than how to find the index of the slice. I may be wrong but in this case the question should be reworded ...

Comment: Hey Hoki and othr friends, as you have mentioned, my supervisor told me its correct. Thank your everyone for your valuable comments :D

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat difficult to understand your question, but it sounds like you would like a histogram of your row data near f = 90 KHz.  If that's true, I think this should work:

```
%find the f2 value closest to 90000: 
[f0, index] = min(abs(f2-90000));

%make a histogram of the data:
histogram(amp(:,index),10);
```